# Blazor validate unmodified form

Tags: asp.net, blazor, asp.net5

I want to validate a Blazor form even though the user hasn't changed the value of any form fields. (By default, Blazor only validates fields after they are modified.)

How can I validate the form without requiring user interaction (editing a field, clicking a button, etc.)? I want to validate the form when it initially shows.

Here is my code:

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@page "/"

<EditForm Model="@formModel" Context="currentEditContext">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <p>
        <label>My Text: <InputText @bind-Value="formModel.Text" /></label>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => formModel.Text)" />
    </p>

    <p>Form valid: @currentEditContext.Validate()</p>
</EditForm>

@code
{
    FormModel formModel = new();

    private class FormModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
```

I tried using various methods on my `EditContext` object, but none of them triggered validation.

- `editContext.Validate();`
- `editContext.NotifyValidationStateChanged();`
- `editContext.NotifyFieldChanged(editContext.Field("Text"));`

Comment: Ran into the  exact same issue, but your answer below didn't work for me. Would you mind updating with working code snippet?

Comment: @User123, I discovered the "Form valid" message wasn't displaying the correct value upon initial load. Is that what you mean by "didn't work"? See the revised answer.

Comment: The issue I'm running into is my form validates if the user interacts with any of the required fields (like typing something and the removing everything for a required field, or for a checkbox checking and and then unchecking it). But if they were to go ahead and hit the save button without any interaction it posts the blank object back (without validation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that I can trigger the form validation by running `editContext.Validate()` inside `OnAfterRender()`.

This code validates the form immediately upon loading the page:

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@page "/"

<EditForm EditContext="editContext">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <p>
        <label>My Text: <InputText @bind-Value="formModel.Text" /></label>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => formModel.Text)" />
    </p>

    <p>Form valid: @(!editContext.GetValidationMessages().Any())</p>
</EditForm>

@code
{
    FormModel formModel = new();
    EditContext editContext;

    private class FormModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; } = "";
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        editContext = new(formModel);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            editContext.Validate();
            StateHasChanged(); // Update the "Form valid" message
        }

        base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Using OnAfterRender together with OnInitialized solved a similar problem for me. But I use OnAfterRenderAsync instead (.NET 5).